# Weird exception thrown when connecting to Oracle from C#

Tags: c#, oracle, database-connection

I am trying to connect the Oracle database on my computer (localhost) from my C# code. I have the following simple code and connection string:

```
class AccessToOracleMigrator
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string oradb = "Data Source=localhost:1521/XE User Id=MWBREP Password=MWBREP Integrated Security=no";

        OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradb);  // C#
        conn.Open();
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();


    }
}
```

The code throws an exception when trying to run conn.Open(); line. The exception detail says: "ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor". I think my connection string is missing some information but I could not find a meaningful explanation. What may be missing here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: doesnt look like a valid connectionstring

Comment: What is missing in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ConnectionString ist not valid as i said.

Take a look to the following link to find out whats wrong:

[OracleConnection.ConnectionString Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracleconnection.connectionstring(v=vs.110).aspx)

Maybe you are just missing the `;` between the connectionString properties

```
string oradb = "Data Source=localhost:1521/XE;User Id=MWBREP;Password=MWBREP;Integrated Security=no";
```

Comment: I changed the connection string as string oradb = "Data Source=localhost:1521/XE;User Id=MWBREP;Password=MWBREP"; and it did not throw exception. I think it is really the missing ; which was the problem.